# Probability of black sock

Tags: probability

this is an easy problem, but i feel i am stuck some whether conceptually.

A man has 3 pairs of black socks and 2 pairs of brown socks kept together in a box.If he dressed hurriedly in the dark, the probability that after he has put on a black sock, he will then put on another black socks is what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that the first sock he draws is black is $\frac{6}{6+4}=\frac35$. Similarly the probability that the second sock is black is $\frac {5}{5+4}=\frac {5}{9}$. Hence total probability is  $\frac35.\frac59=\frac13$

Comment: Why are u multiplying the probability of drawing first black sock? Isnt the ques asking the probability of second black sock given the first black sock is drawn?

Comment: @excuse_dont_exist yes but we want the first sock to be black first

Comment: @DwijRajHari You'e calculated the probability that two socks are black, but this was not the question as we know that the first one was black sock already.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I too think the question is a little ambiguous. I think it means -what is the probability that the guy will put on another black sock after putting on a black sock. So it is not that the first event has already happened. The question wants us to find the probability of  drawing two black socks consecutively.

Comment: It's as unambiguous as it can be: "the probability that *after he has put on a black sock*, he will *then* put on another black socks is what?"

Answer (score 1):

If the socks are all loose in the box, then there are $6$ black and $4$ brown floating around initially.

Once he has a black sock on, there are $5$ black and $4$ brown remaining.

The probability that the next sock he takes out of the box is black is $\frac{5}{5+4}=\frac{5}{9}$.

Comment: exactly even i got the same answer but the answer is given 1/3

Comment: Does the question ask about brown socks? If he had one brown sock on, then the probability of getting another brown would be $\frac{3}{9}=\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: No it clearly says 'black'